# D3 Stable Sort Simulation

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom, d3.js

I am attempting to simulate a stable sort using the d3.selection.sort() function. For each data member, I have two divs, and I would like to sort primarily based on a time property of the data, and then by a class which I have added to the divs. However, since the d3.sort function just passes in the data (please correct me if I'm wrong), I cannot access the classes efficiently (I could d3 select again but this would be very inefficient). Instead, I am attempting to add a property dynamically to the data while adding the class, so I can use it in the sort later. However, I am running into problems binding data properly, when I change data in one selection it changes in all of the elements bound to that data member.

```
enterSelect = d3.selectAll('div').data(dates).enter();

enterSelect.append('div').attr('class', function(d) { d.sort = 1; return "class_1"})
enterSelect.append('div').attr('class', function(d) { d.sort = 2; return "class_2"})

main.selectAll('div').sort(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(a.date, b.date) || d3.ascending(a.sort, b.sort)});
```

But at this point all elements have d.sort == 2. Any thoughts on how to fix this. Thank you!

Edit: So in the end I want to have

```
<div class=1> data[0] </div>
<div class=2> data[0] </div>
<div class=1> data[1] </div>
<div class=2> data[1] </div>
<div class=1> data[2] </div>
<div class=2> data[2] </div>
```

and I am starting with

```
<div class=1> data[0] </div>
<div class=1> data[1] </div>
<div class=1> data[3] </div>
<div class=2> data[0] </div>
<div class=2> data[1] </div>
<div class=2> data[2] </div>
```

where each data element also has a .date property to sort by. Then I want to secondary sort on class, or simulate this somehow. Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve by changing the data dynamically. What determines the sort order of the two sets of `div`s? And why do you have two sets of `div`s? A solution may be to bind the data only to a single set of `div`s, each of which contains two nested `div`s.

Comment: Lars, thanks for the response. Nested `div`s would be much easier, but unfortunately I need unnested divs, I will edit to make this more clear, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you wouldn't be able to do this directly with D3's sort for the reasons you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the solution with JQuery instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented solution with JQuery

```
    var myList = $('div.displayTimeline');
    var listItems = myList.children('div').get(); 
    listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
       var dateA = formatTime.parse($(a).data('id'));
       var dateB = formatTime.parse($(b).data('id'));
       var sortA = $(a).data('sort')
       var sortB = $(b).data('sort')
       return (dateA < dateB) ? -1 : (dateA > dateB) ? 1 : 
                ((sortA < sortB) ? -1 : (sortA > sortB) ? 1 : 0);
    })
    $.each(listItems, function(idx, itm) { myList.append(itm); });
```